# GROUP BY same record but different TIMESTAMP/DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to `GROUP BY` same records but different `timestamp` or `datetime`.
The difference of time is only about 3 minutes from the first entry.

example:

This is what the database table looks like.

```
*-------------------------------------------*
|   id  |   name    |         time          |
|   1   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:00:10   |
|   2   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:01:11   |
|   3   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:01:15   |
|   4   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:01:16   |
|   5   |   Anna    | 2018-02-21 12:03:11   |
|   6   |   Anna    | 2018-02-21 12:03:13   |
|   7   |   Bell    | 2018-02-21 12:05:01   |
|   8   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:10:00   |
*-------------------------------------------*
```

I want to get Lei's entry from 12:00:10 up to 3 minutes from her first `timestamp` or `datetime` record.

so the output would be like this.

```
*-------------------------------------------*
|   id  |   name    |         time          |
|   1   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:00:10   |
|   5   |   Anna    | 2018-02-21 12:03:11   |
|   7   |   Bell    | 2018-02-21 12:05:01   |
|   8   |   Lei     | 2018-02-21 12:10:00   |
*-------------------------------------------*
```

I'll be gladly appreciate your help, mysql or php it is.

Comment: The sample output  doesn't make sense. Is Anna's id really supposed to be 2? Should it not remain 5? I assume the id is auto-incremented right?

Comment: Sorry, @MonkeyZeus. I forgot about that logic, I editted it already. Thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: np, what should the output look like if there was this record in your table? `8 | Lei | 2018-02-21 12:10:10`

Comment: okay I'll post an example of that too

Comment: Hi, I already did it. :) @MonkeyZeus

Comment: Nice, I hope you don't mind but I merged the data for legibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bad3aa/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(4), `time` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `name`, `time`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Lei', '2018-02-21 12:00:10'),
    (2, 'Lei', '2018-02-21 12:01:11'),
    (3, 'Lei', '2018-02-21 12:01:15'),
    (4, 'Lei', '2018-02-21 12:01:16'),
    (5, 'Anna', '2018-02-21 12:03:11'),
    (6, 'Anna', '2018-02-21 12:03:13'),
    (7, 'Bell', '2018-02-21 12:05:01')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select id, name, min(time) as time
from Table1 
group by name
order by time
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bad3aa/6/0)**:

```
    | id | name |                 time |
    |----|------|----------------------|
    |  1 |  Lei | 2018-02-21T12:00:10Z |
    |  5 | Anna | 2018-02-21T12:03:11Z |
    |  7 | Bell | 2018-02-21T12:05:01Z |
```

OR if you want to group by interval 3 minute you can do it like this

```
select id, name, min(time) as time
from Table1 
group by name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) DIV 180
order by time
;
```

Comment: OP's question states `I want to get Lei's entry from 12:00:10 up to 3 minutes from her first timestamp or datetime record.` So if there is an ID #8 for Lei at 12:10:10 then the output should have Lei as a fourth record. Does your SQL cover that?

Comment: I like it but unfortunately it only "sort of" works. I tried adding another entry for Lei at `2018-02-21 12:03:00` but that produces another row for the output. However, `2018-02-21 12:02:59` produces the expected result. Looks like `DIV` is somehow minute-based?

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, I'll try this. I'll send you my response after I found the result. :)

Comment: Wow @anon, thanks for this. This is a new knowledge added for me. <3 This works fine now, and it helps a lot! Thanks again!

Comment: This answer would not work (as requested) if a row had `'Lei'/'12:04:05'`.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data, you don't need to consider the timestamp at all:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, name, min(time) as time
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
group by id, name;
```

Grouping things by three minute intervals, from the first record in the interval is much harder.  This requires either variables or recursive CTEs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding.. but can you explain your answer? :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for helping me out. Unfortunately I already found an answer. Too bad I can't vote up too, I still have little reputation but this is really helping! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this:

```
select *
from mytable t
where not exists (
  select *
  from mytable t1
  where t1.name =  t.name
    and t1.id   <> t.id
    and t1.time >= t.time - interval 3 minute
    and t1.time <  t.time
);
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03cf16/1

It will select rows only if no row with the same `name` exists within a three munutes interval.